# "Could not compute output Tensor" error in Keras Functional API

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am learning to use tensorflow keras functional api.
I am building neural network that takes 2 inputs and produces binary output(0/1).

Code for Model:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,horizontal_flip=True,rotation_range=15,validation_split=0.2)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('lfw',
                                                    target_size=(224,224),
                                                    class_mode='binary',
                                                    shuffle=True,
                                                    seed=24                                                    
                                                    )

input1 = Input(shape=(224,224,3),name='Input_1')
input2 = Input(shape=(224,224,3),name="Input_2")
vgg =  VGG16(False,'imagenet',input_shape=(224,224,3))
vgg.trainable = False
encoder1 = vgg(input1)
encoder2 = vgg(input2)
difference_layer = Subtract(name="Difference_Layer")([encoder1,encoder2])
h1 = Flatten(name='Flatten')(difference_layer)
output = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid',name="Output")(h1)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input1,input2],outputs=[output])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss=tf.keras.losses.MSE,metrics=['acc','mse','loss'])

model.fit(train_generator,epochs=10)
```

I am getting this error:

```
AssertionError: in user code:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:505 train_function  *
    outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:951 run  **
    return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2290 call_for_each_replica
    return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2649 _call_for_each_replica
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:465 train_step  **
    y_pred = self(x, training=True)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:927 __call__
    outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py:714 call
    convert_kwargs_to_constants=base_layer_utils.call_context().saving)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py:894 _run_internal_graph
    assert str(id(x)) in tensor_dict, 'Could not compute output ' + str(x)

AssertionError: Could not compute output Tensor("Output_4/Identity:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: I imagine you are mixing `keras` and `tf.keras`?

Comment: I rechecked. I've imported everything required from tf.keras.

Comment: Are your files really images?
Get a batch from the generator: `x, y = train_generator[0]` and see the shapes, the ranges, etc., of `x` and `y`.

Comment: The shapes are fine. Each folder contains some images associated with the folder. Images are loaded fine. I also tried chaning different parameters such as making datagenerator sparse, trying different loss function, etc.

Comment: How many folders?

Comment: I figured out the problem. My model expects 2 inputs but ImageDataGenerator feeds one images at a time. Thank you for your time.